# Driver/Kext Realtek 8191SE - Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4

Tags: macos, mac, wifi, network, driver

I want to develop for the iPhone and I have installed Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4 on my laptop. However, I don't have any driver/kext for wireless with Realtek 8191SE that runs on this OS. I have tried to install drivers/kexts from this family but they will not run.

Comment: Is this a non-Apple computer you've installed OS X on? Are you trying to build a Hackintosh?

Comment: And no need to apologize for your English: your grammar is better than most of the native speakers of US English I work with.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the kext is for 32 bit mode only and does not work when running in 64 bit mode. Boot your Mac in 32 bit mode and check whether is works then. (If your Mac uses the 64-bit kernel by default, you can start up with the 32-bit kernel by holding the 3 and 2 keys during startup.)